# How to add Item based on ID to List and Bind to dropdownlist in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I have a method which gets project name and id based on Client id using Linq

```
    public SelectList GetClientProjects(int clientId){

     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> clientProjectsList = 
        (from client in res.CLIENT
         join clientProj in res.CLIENT_PROJECT
         on client.ID equals clientProj.CLIENT_ID
         join project in res.PROJECT
         on clientProj.PROJ_ID equals project.ID
         where client.IS_DELETED == "N" && clientProj.IS_DELETED
                   == "N" && project.IS_DELETED 
                   == "N" && client.ID == clientId
         select project).AsEnumerable().Select(projs => new SelectListItem() {
                                  Text=projs.NAME, Value=projs.ID.ToString() });
        return new SelectList(clientProjectsList, "Value", "Text", PROJ_ID);
    }
```

Now, I am getting client id by following query

```
var clientDetails = reslandentity.CLIENT.
Where(m => m.SUBSCRIBER_ID == userid).ToList();
```

By this, how can get Project name and Project id and how to bind to dropdown list with ProjectId and Populate project Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var clientDetails = reslandentity.CLIENT.Where(m => m.SUBSCRIBER_ID == userid);
 List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
 foreach (var item in clientDetails)
 {
    var clientProjectsList =
          (from client in reslandentity.CLIENT
           join clientProj in reslandentity.CLIENT_PROJECT
           on client.ID equals clientProj.CLIENT_ID
           join project in reslandentity.PROJECT
           on clientProj.PROJ_ID equals project.ID
           where client.IS_DELETED == "N" && clientProj.IS_DELETED
                     == "N" && project.IS_DELETED
                     == "N" && client.ID == item.ID
           select project).FirstOrDefault();
            if (clientProjectsList != null)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = clientProjectsList.NAME, Value = clientProjectsList.ID.ToString() });
            }
 }
 SelectList list=new SelectList(items,"Value","Text",model.PROJ_ID);
 ViewBag.ProjectsList = list;
```

Bind to dropdown list like

```
@Html.Dropdownlistfor(m=>m.Proj_Id,(SelectList)ViewBag.ProjectsList)
```

Hope you got expected result.